# iterate through number of columns, with variable columns

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix

For example, let's consider this toy code

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd  

a = rnd.randint(0,10,(10,10))
k = (1,2)
b = a[:,k]

for col in np.arange(np.size(b,1)):
    b[:,col] = b[:,col]+col*100
```

This code will work when the size of `k` is bigger than 1. However, with the size equal to 1, the extracted sub-matrix from `a` is transformed into a row vector, and applying the function in the `for` loop throws an error.
 Of course, I could fix this by checking the dimension of `b` and reshaping:

```
if np.dim(b) == 1: 
    b = np.reshape(b, (np.size(b), 1))
```

in order to obtain a column vector, but this is expensive.

So, the question is: what is the best way to handle this situation?
This seems like something that would arise quite often and I wonder what is the best strategy to deal with it.

Comment: Reshaping can be inexpensive using `b.shape = (np.size(b),1)` instead since this is done inplace with no intermediate copy and reassignment of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you index with a list or tuple, the 2d shape is preserved:

```
In [638]: a=np.random.randint(0,10,(10,10))
In [639]: a[:,(1,2)].shape
Out[639]: (10, 2)
In [640]: a[:,(1,)].shape
Out[640]: (10, 1)
```

And I think `b` iteration can be simplified to:

```
a[:,k] += np.arange(len(k))*100
```

This sort of calculation will also be easier is `k` is always a list or tuple, and never a scalar (a scalar does not have a `len`).

`np.column_stack` ensures its inputs are 2d (and expands at the end if not) with:

```
 if arr.ndim < 2:
     arr = array(arr, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T
```

`np.atleast_2d` does

```
 elif len(ary.shape) == 1:
     result = ary[newaxis,:]
```

which of course could changed in this case to

```
 if b.ndim==1:
     b = b[:,None]
```

Any ways, I think it is better to ensure the `k` is a tuple rather than adjust `b` shape after.  But keep both options in your toolbox.